# how to append a SAP UI5 control to radiobutton control

Tags: sapui5

I have a custom radiobutton js class that extends sap.m.RadioButton. in its property I have a control and I want to append that control to the radiobutton. The radioButton is being used in a radioButtonGroup control.

let say I want to append Input control to radiobutton
my input is as following

```
let oInput = new sap.m.Input({
    width: "100%",
    type: sap.m.InputType.Text,
    enabled: true
});
//adding then input to radiobutton - this refers to radiobutton
this.$().append("<div>" + oInput + "</div>");
```

this does not work they way I want as I see that a text such as "Element sap.m.Input#__input22" gets appended to the control.
I tried to do something like this:

```
this.$().append("<div>" + oInput.getDomRef() + "</div>");
```

and didn't work. Any tips ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to a create a composite control than extending RadioButton control
e.g. https://jsbin.com/puqopam/edit?js,output

```js
sap.ui.define([
  'sap/ui/core/Control',
  'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel',
  'sap/m/RadioButton',
  'sap/m/Input'
], function (Control, JSONModel, RadioButton, Input) {
  Control.extend('RadioButtonEx', {
    metadata: {
      aggregations: {
        radio: { type: 'sap.m.RadioButton', multiple: false },
        input: { type: 'sap.m.Input', multiple: false }
      },
    },

    renderer: function (rm, oControl) {
      rm.write('<div');
      rm.writeControlData(oControl);
      rm.write('>');
      rm.write('<div>');
      rm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation('radio'));
      rm.write('</div>');
      rm.write('<div>');
      rm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation('input'));
      rm.write('</div>');
      rm.write('</div>');
    }
  });

  var combo = new RadioButtonEx({
    radio: new RadioButton({
      text: "test"
    }),
    input: new Input()
  });

  combo.placeAt("content")
});
```